# xcodes automatic classmodel: how to fix a missing inheritance-link

Tags: xcode, model, uml

i have in my project a mainpage interited from uiviewcontroller. and any subpage is inherited from a subviewcontroller, that is an inherited uiviewcontroller, just with some overwritten behaviours and some new functions.

problem in that case is, that the class-model generated by xcode does not display that one inheritation between uiviewcontroller and subviewcontroller. how can i bring xcode to make this arrow there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i publicate one funktion in the SubViewController, the graphic is correct, even if this is programmaticaly nonsens.

Answer (score 0):

The class-model does *not* affect *anything* with your code. As long as your class is said to inherit from UIViewController `SubViewController : UIViewController` then you are fine. Depending on how many classes you are modeling at once you may have hundreds of lines very close together and you may not be able to see a specific arrow unless you drag your SubViewController way away from everything else. try selecting just that class and see if you get the arrow then. Even if you don't see the arrow it does not mean you have a problem, if you want to be sure that UIViewController is the superclass of SubViewController then just add this chunk of code to your SubViewController class:

```
+(void)initialize {
NSLog(@"My class is: %@, my superclass is: %@.", [self class], [self superclass]);
}
```

Comment: dont understand it wrong. everything works. i am just missing the link in the documentation i have to do for this project. and yes, there is really no arrow between those two classes, but they are definitely "linked"